# Title -- >How to use my custom catalog in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Suppose I generated my custom extensions via module gen and I created my own product and content catalog how can I use mine catalog instead of out of the box (powertools)?

[image: Catalog impex]

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it on Base Store Catalogs configuration in backoffice. Also you can use impex for updating it.